# How to make a div always be positioned in a single location on the screen?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, coding-style

I have a div with a textarea and a submit button, but I would like this div to be positioned in a single location on the screen regardless of what happens.

[image]

As you can see, the textarea is in a single screen placement, but every time I send messages it goes down, like it does here

[image]

I want this textarea of ​​mine to be positioned at the end of the screen, without going down or up because of the messages

HTML

```
  <div className='messageText'>
    <textarea  
      name="" 
      id="" 
      cols="30" 
      rows="10"  
      placeholder='Digite sua mensagem...'
      value={message}
      onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
     ></textarea>
    <button onClick={handleSendMessage}>Enviar</button>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.messageText {
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 4vh;
}

.messageText textarea {
 border-radius: 6px;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 width: 50%;
 height: 10vh;
 background-color: #3d3939;
 color: #fff; 
}

.messageText button {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 10vh;
  background-color: #ff914d;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
}
```

Comment: Use `position: fixed` on .messageText

Comment: use position property like fixed absolute whatever you think will work for you

Comment: I did that and still with the same problem, every time I send a message my textarea goes down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using position: fixed you can achieve what you want

```css
footer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100px;
}

.messageText {
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.messageText textarea {
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: #3d3939;
  color: #fff;
}

.messageText button {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 10vh;
  background-color: #ff914d;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="messageText">
    <textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem..."></textarea>
    <button>Enviar</button>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: I know it has nothing to do with it, but do you have any advice on how to introduce a message scroll?

Comment: Set the height of your messages container to a fixed height (eg. 1000px) and set overflow: auto

Comment: This worked but some messages lag behind my textarea

Comment: Create another question and people will help you there

Answer (score 2):

@Bernard Borg already Answered the question before me. I will still submit the answer just for another example.

As he mentions use `position: fixed;` then you can easily achieve it.

Ignore the demo text used to scroll the div.

```css
.TextAreaDiv{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
.MessageArea{
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<div class="MessageArea">
<h3>quotes</h3>
 <blockquote>
   This a long quotations
   For 50 years, WWF has been protecting the future of nature. The world's leading conservation organization, WWF works in 100 countries and is supported by 1.2 million members in the United States and close to 5 million globally. 
   <br>
   <q>can nested some short quote</q>
</blockquote> 
<q>This is a short quotations</q>
<hr>
<h3>preformatted</h3>
 <pre>
Text in a pre element
is displayed in a fixed-width
font, and it preserves
both      spaces and
line breaks
</pre> 
<hr>
<h3>abbreviations</h3>
<p>
  The HTML &lt;abbr&gt; element represents an abbreviation and optionally provides a full description for it. <br>
  Demo below <br>
  The <abbr title="World Health Organization">WHO</abbr> was founded in 1948. </p>
<hr>
<h3>address</h3>
<p>Demo using &lt;address&gt; tag to display address
  <address>
    Written by <a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com">Jon Doe</a>.<br>
    Visit us at:<br>
    Example.com<br>
    Box 564, Disneyland<br>
    USA
  </address> 
<hr>
<h3>citation</h3>
 <p><cite>The Scream</cite> by Edward Munch. Painted in 1893.</p> 
<hr>
</div>
<div class="TextAreaDiv">

<div class="input-group mb-3">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Send message" aria-label="Send message" aria-describedby="button-send">
      <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="button-send">Send</button>
      </div>
 </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Great solution, thanks. Do you have any advice on how to make the message scroll visible?

Comment: @Routfin You can use this `overflow: scroll;`. I updated the answer I hope this example will help  `.MessageArea{
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 350px;
}`

Comment: Yep, that worked. But some messages are behind the textarea

Comment: @Routfin then you can adjust the height of the div `height: 350px;` reduce the height.

Comment: Check the Answer I reduced the height from `350` to `150` and now it's looking good on the small screen of Code Snippet.